# Python re.search newline

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to search for and find the string found after value=. I am successful doing so when their is only one space in the provided string, such as this

```
id="test" value="123"
```

However, in the case below their appears to be 10 whitespace sections, including a new line being created.

```
id="test"
         value="123"
```

The code below cannot find the string for value= and I can't figure out how to get it to work

```
searchObj = re.search( r'id=\"test\"\s{10,}value=\"(.*?)\"', var, re.M|re.I)

if searchObj:
  var4 = searchObj.group()
  print 3
  print var4
else:
  print "Nothing found!!"
```

the code above does not print 3 or the actual var4

Comment: if you are parsing html, use a htmlparser

Answer (score 2):

```
searchObj = re.search( r'id="test"\s+value="(.*?)"', var, re.I)
```

Use this.`\s{10,}` will only match if there `10` or more.So make it `+`.

```
x='''id="test"
     value="123"'''

print re.search(r'id="test"\s+value="(.*?)"',x, re.I)
```

Output:`<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000022AF120>`

Comment: r'id=\"test\"\s+value=\"(_.*?)\"', var, re.I) - does not work for parsing the above snippet, given it creates a new line

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine for me.

However, it's usually best to be a little more permissive in matching whitespace, so a better pattern would be

```
r'id=\"test\"\s+value=\"(.*?)\"'
```

The `+` following the `\s` indicates that you want to match one or more whitespace characters.

Comment: was my own mistake - had something included that should not have been :) ty

Answer (score 0):

As a more general approach to solving this, the following kind of regular expression could be used to extact both items:

```
test = """
id="test"
         value="123"
"""

reIdValue = re.search(r'\s+id="(.*?)"\s+value="(.*?)"', test)

print reIdValue.groups()
print reIdValue.group(1)
print reIdValue.group(2)
```

This would display:

```
('test', '123')
test
123
```